# Pandas DataFrame slice data on non-unique timestamps

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame consisting of packets containing measurements with a timestamp index. Flag packets indicating the beginning and end of a measurement section are interspersed within the message. An example of this follows:

```
                         dev    node   meas 0   meas 1  ...
tstp
2016-04-12 03:42:16.238  instr  None  [val]    [val]
2016-04-12 03:42:16.338  cntrl  101   [val]    [val]
2016-04-12 03:42:16.442  instr  None  [val]    [val]
2016-04-12 03:42:16.445  instr  None  [val]    [val]
2016-04-12 03:42:16.445  cntrl  101   [val]    [val]
2016-04-12 03:42:16.448  instr  None  [val]    [val]
2016-04-12 03:42:16.540  instr  None  [val]    [val]
2016-04-12 03:42:16.600  cntrl  101   [val]    [val]
2016-04-12 03:42:16.639  instr  None  [val]    [val]
2016-04-12 03:42:16.741  instr  None  [val]    [val]
2016-04-12 03:42:17.238  instr  None  [val]    [val]
2016-04-12 03:42:17.338  cntrl  102   [val]    [val]
2016-04-12 03:42:17.442  instr  None  [val]    [val]
2016-04-12 03:42:17.445  instr  None  [val]    [val]
2016-04-12 03:42:17.445  cntrl  102   [val]    [val]
2016-04-12 03:42:17.448  instr  None  [val]    [val]
2016-04-12 03:42:17.540  instr  None  [val]    [val]
2016-04-12 03:42:17.600  cntrl  102   [val]    [val]
2016-04-12 03:42:17.639  instr  None  [val]    [val]
2016-04-12 03:42:17.741  instr  None  [val]    [val]
```

What I'm trying to do is:

```
for name, group in pkts.groupby('node') :
    beg = group.index[0]
    end = group.index[-1]

    # pseudocode
    pkts[ beg:end & pkts.dev=='instr' , 'node' ] = name
```

Direct slicing of beg:end doesn't work since non-unique values. Can anyone offer some insights or a better way to do this?

**UPDATE** (clarification):

Purpose: to easily access measurements from "instr" device based upon node number. "instr" device is unable to transmit node value.

Desired output (originally intended, open to suggestions):

```
                         dev    node   meas 0   meas 1  ...
tstp
2016-04-12 03:42:16.238  instr  None  [val]    [val]
2016-04-12 03:42:16.338  cntrl  101   [val]    [val]
2016-04-12 03:42:16.442  instr  101   [val]    [val]
2016-04-12 03:42:16.445  instr  101   [val]    [val]
2016-04-12 03:42:16.445  cntrl  101   [val]    [val]
2016-04-12 03:42:16.448  instr  101   [val]    [val]
2016-04-12 03:42:16.540  instr  101   [val]    [val]
2016-04-12 03:42:16.600  cntrl  101   [val]    [val]
2016-04-12 03:42:16.639  instr  None  [val]    [val]
2016-04-12 03:42:16.741  instr  None  [val]    [val]
2016-04-12 03:42:17.238  instr  None  [val]    [val]
2016-04-12 03:42:17.338  cntrl  102   [val]    [val]
2016-04-12 03:42:17.442  instr  102   [val]    [val]
2016-04-12 03:42:17.445  instr  102   [val]    [val]
2016-04-12 03:42:17.445  cntrl  102   [val]    [val]
2016-04-12 03:42:17.448  instr  102   [val]    [val]
2016-04-12 03:42:17.540  instr  102   [val]    [val]
2016-04-12 03:42:17.600  cntrl  102   [val]    [val]
2016-04-12 03:42:17.639  instr  None  [val]    [val]
2016-04-12 03:42:17.741  instr  None  [val]    [val]
```

Comment: Is it possible a simple `.fillna('ffill')` could solve your problem? Can you express abstractly what you are looking to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to align the data. So If I want to select the measurements from the instrumentation device by node '101', it will be labeled. Those measurements will be between the first and last instance of 101 for the control device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can create `Multiindex` from `index` by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), then [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) `None` to `NaN` and use [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with method `ffill` and `bfill`:

```
pkts = pkts.reset_index().set_index('tstp', append=True)
print pkts
                              dev  node meas 0 meas 1
   tstp                                              
0  2016-04-12 03:42:16.238  instr  None  [val]  [val]
1  2016-04-12 03:42:16.338  cntrl   101  [val]  [val]
2  2016-04-12 03:42:16.442  instr  None  [val]  [val]
3  2016-04-12 03:42:16.445  instr  None  [val]  [val]
4  2016-04-12 03:42:16.445  cntrl   101  [val]  [val]
5  2016-04-12 03:42:16.448  instr  None  [val]  [val]
6  2016-04-12 03:42:16.540  instr  None  [val]  [val]
7  2016-04-12 03:42:16.600  cntrl   101  [val]  [val]
8  2016-04-12 03:42:16.639  instr  None  [val]  [val]
9  2016-04-12 03:42:16.741  instr  None  [val]  [val]
10 2016-04-12 03:42:16.238  instr  None  [val]  [val]
11 2016-04-12 03:42:16.338  cntrl   102  [val]  [val]
12 2016-04-12 03:42:16.442  instr  None  [val]  [val]
13 2016-04-12 03:42:16.445  instr  None  [val]  [val]
14 2016-04-12 03:42:16.445  cntrl   102  [val]  [val]
15 2016-04-12 03:42:16.448  instr  None  [val]  [val]
16 2016-04-12 03:42:16.540  instr  None  [val]  [val]
17 2016-04-12 03:42:16.600  cntrl   102  [val]  [val]
18 2016-04-12 03:42:16.639  instr  None  [val]  [val]
19 2016-04-12 03:42:16.741  instr  None  [val]  [val]

pkts['node'] = pkts['node'].replace('None',np.nan)

for name, group in pkts.groupby('node'):
    beg = group.index[0]
    end = group.index[-1]
#    print beg
#    print end
    pkts.loc[ beg:end,'node' ] = pkts.loc[ beg:end,'node' ].fillna(method='ffill')
                                                           .fillna(method='bfill')
```

```
print pkts 
                              dev node meas 0 meas 1
   tstp                                             
0  2016-04-12 03:42:16.238  instr  NaN  [val]  [val]
1  2016-04-12 03:42:16.338  cntrl  101  [val]  [val]
2  2016-04-12 03:42:16.442  instr  101  [val]  [val]
3  2016-04-12 03:42:16.445  instr  101  [val]  [val]
4  2016-04-12 03:42:16.445  cntrl  101  [val]  [val]
5  2016-04-12 03:42:16.448  instr  101  [val]  [val]
6  2016-04-12 03:42:16.540  instr  101  [val]  [val]
7  2016-04-12 03:42:16.600  cntrl  101  [val]  [val]
8  2016-04-12 03:42:16.639  instr  NaN  [val]  [val]
9  2016-04-12 03:42:16.741  instr  NaN  [val]  [val]
10 2016-04-12 03:42:16.238  instr  NaN  [val]  [val]
11 2016-04-12 03:42:16.338  cntrl  102  [val]  [val]
12 2016-04-12 03:42:16.442  instr  102  [val]  [val]
13 2016-04-12 03:42:16.445  instr  102  [val]  [val]
14 2016-04-12 03:42:16.445  cntrl  102  [val]  [val]
15 2016-04-12 03:42:16.448  instr  102  [val]  [val]
16 2016-04-12 03:42:16.540  instr  102  [val]  [val]
17 2016-04-12 03:42:16.600  cntrl  102  [val]  [val]
18 2016-04-12 03:42:16.639  instr  NaN  [val]  [val]
19 2016-04-12 03:42:16.741  instr  NaN  [val]  [val]
```

Comment: I don't want to fill with 'name', I want to fill with the iterable's value for name i.e. 101, 102, etc.

Comment: Sory, each None by groupby can be filled by `101,101,101,...` and `102,102,102,...` or `101,102,103,...` and `104,105,106,...`

Comment: So how do I replace the values from pkts1 into pkts? Something like join right ?

Comment: I dont know if I undesrstand correctly what do you need. Can you add to your question desired output? Are always `None` values of column `node` in rows where are value `instr` of column `dev`? If not, can you change sample?

Comment: Clarification added.